# WPF ListViewItem focus selects second row

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I have search `TextBox`, and I want to when I press *Arrow Down* to navigate through the `ListView`, and if I press *Left/Right* Arrow on `ListView` I want to navigate with *Caret* through the text, and if I press down again I navigate through the `ListView` again. Just regular process like Chrome Search suggestions.

I just want to get *Focus* like when pressing **TAB** button. With TAB all works great.

On `TextBox` I use `PreviewKeyDown` event and detect `Key.Down` and I set my `ListView.Focus()` - That works great. `ListView` is focused and I can Navigate through items.

On `ListView` I use `PreviewKeyDown` event and detect any key that is not `Key.Down` or `Key.Up` and set focus on `TextBox` and set selection to the end of text. - That works great. `Textbox` is focused and I can Navigate through the text with Left/Right arrow.

Problem is now if I press *Down* arrow. Nothing happens. I can't get focus on `ListView` again. Don't know why.

I used `Keyboard.Focus()`, `Keyboard.ClearFocus()`, `FocusManager`... Nothing helps, focus remain on `TextBox`.

I used `ItemContainerGenerator` with `SelectedIndex` and that works but Selects second item in `ListView`. I think it is because I select first index and when I press down `ListView` gets focus and pass that *Arrow Down* event. And I ending with second row in `ListView`.

`TextBox` on `PreviewKeyDown`:

```
private void SearchTermTextBox_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down) {
            SuggestionsListView.Focus();
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
        {
            SearchTermTextBox.Clear();
        }
    }
```

`ListView` on `PreviewKeyDown`:

```
private void SuggestionsListView_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Key != Key.Down && e.Key != Key.Up) {
            SearchTermTextBox.Focus();
            SearchTermTextBox.Select(SearchTermTextBox.Text.Length, 0);
        }
    }
```

I used this code with `ItemContainerGenerator`. But, like I said, it's selecting second row from some reason.

```
SuggestionsListView.SelectedItem = SuggestionsListView.Items[0];
            ListViewItem item = SuggestionsListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(SuggestionsListView.SelectedItem) as ListViewItem;
            item.Focus();
```

Comment: I've had the same problem before. Although I never fixed it, I discovered that the `TextBox` doesn't actually keep the focus, it gets it *back* immediately after the `ListBox` gets it. There's some weird interaction going on there. I also found that adding `e.Handled = true` after giving the `ListBox` the focus partially works. The `ListBox` gets the focus, but pressing the down key again loses it.

Comment: In your last code fragment, instead of setting the `SelectedItem`, try setting the `SelectedIndex` to `0`.